# Change screen luminosity [Ubuntu Server 22.04.1]

Tags: command-line, server, brightness

I'm trying to change the luminosity of my laptop running ubuntu server. tried using `xbacklight -set 30` but it will return `RANDR Query Version' returned error -1` still does not change the brightness, any other terminal only way / server way?

Comment: I don't think you can change brightness in console ;-)

Comment: well i hope you can change the screen brightness

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with my ASUS Zenbook UM5302ta running ubuntu 22.04 with i3.

The command I assume should work is `xbacklight -d eDP -inc 5` where eDp is the display I'm connected to (output from running `xrandr`)

What I've discovered is is that I can change value in file `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness` that actually changes the brightness of the screen.

- min value - 0
- max value - content of `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/max_brightness`

you can get all the information on [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight)